Any way I can practice big O notations for probability and statistics?
I have been using Taylor expansion to get some feelings and many approximating results in trying to find innovative ideas for my research. And I have seen a lot of approximate equals or asymptotically equals. I want to make them into equalities and big O notations to make them into rigorous and exact error bounds, e.g., f=g+O(...).
Where should I learn the basics? Is there a systematic way that I can practice and improve? I have only learned undergraduate level real analysis. Do I need to take any other classes? Any help is appreciated.

It's hard to know how to answer this, but most of the time when I am reading big-O questions I realize it's very useful to understand Taylor's Theorem with remainder.  It's the same theorem taught in real analysis but you need to have a deeper understanding of it, because its application to random variables typically requires a quantitative analysis of the error across the full range of the variable rather than for a specific number or within a specific radius.  You might consider hunting down such questions here on CV and pondering the comments and answers they have received.
